# Doctor creates a Robocop-like suit, gets murdered and installed, and goes on a killing spree

Tags: story-identification, space, cyborg

Early 80's I had seen a movie where a dr had created a "Robocop" type suit for space travel. The doc was murdered and installed into his own suit and of course goes on a killing spree for revenge after the baddies kidnap his wife etc etc. All I can remember is the suit had little lights at key muscle points and everytime the wearer started using the suits enhanced strength the lights beeped and flashed brighter and faster the more strength he used. Possibly filmed late 70's, early 80's.

Comment: I swear I remember something like this as well but don't recall the name.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187661/made-for-tv-scifi-movie-scientist-becomes-prototype-cyborg-fights-another-c (which is newer but has a confirmation comment from the OP)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds very similar to The Vindicator, a movie from 1986. In that one, a scientist who was working on a robotic suit is killed by his employer when he finds out what the boss is really up to. His remains are integrated into the suit and he's brought back to life as a remote-controlled cyborg. Once his control chip gets destroyed, though, he goes after the bad guys with a vengeance.

I don't remember any blinking lights, though. See if the trailer looks familiar.